# Deployed Netlify app looks different than production build

Tags: reactjs, deployment, netlify

I deployed my react app on Netlify and everything functions correctly, but the deployed version looks different than my localhost production build. Everything is smaller for some reason and is making the layout different.

This is my first time ever using Netlify so I'm not sure if I missed something simple, but I saw other people had this issue, but never got a clear answer on how to fix it. I guess I could go back and edit all the CSS to make it match up, but there should be a different solution. Here's some screenshots of the difference between the two.

- Local Version: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQYUy.jpg
- Netlify Version: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZoT1j.jpg
- Github repo: https://github.com/alexisbenavidez99/my_portfolio